Understanding Wallpaper Groups: cm and cmm
I am currently studying wallpaper groups but am struggling to understand the specific cases of cm and cmm. According to the following source:

The region shown is a choice of the possible translation cells with minimum area, except for cm and cmm, where a region of twice that area is shown. (Source: Wallpaper group diagrams)

However, I am having trouble understanding why the regions for cm and cmm are described as being composed of two cells. What exactly does this mean?
I've watched several online courses and purchased a book on the topic, but I still haven't been able to find a clear explanation. Could someone help me interpret this?
Thank you in advance for your insights!

The wikipedia article has some explanations on the cells.

I reach it but didn't figure out how cm and cmm cell is explained. I'd be happy if you answer the question.

I cannot explain it bether than it is explained there. For example, see for cm: The group cm contains no rotations. It has reflection axes, all parallel. There is at least one glide reflection whose axis is not a reflection axis; it is halfway between two adjacent parallel reflection axes.

I understand it, but why is it cm, not pm? From the same page, it says In the remaining two cases symmetry description is with respect to centred cells that are larger than the primitive cell, and hence have internal repetition; the directions of their sides is different from those of the translation vectors spanning a primitive cell. However, I still haven't found an internal repetition and an actual primitive cell in cm and in cmm pattern.
